# How to get multiple ids from route param in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I want to fetch multiples ids which I am passing while routing in Angular using route.params.
This is the route.ts

```
{path:'section/:id/:id', component: SubsectionsComponent}
```

And this is how I am routing from a component.ts

```
onSectionClick(id1, id2){
    this.router.navigate(['/path/',id1,id2], {relativeTo:this.route})
  }
```

And this is how I am fetching in the component where it routes.

```
constructor(private route: ActivateRoute){}
this.route.params.subscribe(
      (route)=>{  
        console.log(route)
      }
    )
```

But it is only logging one id from the params.

Comment: use different names in your path. :id1/:id2 for example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use different names in your path. For example:

```
{path:'section/:id1/:id2', component: SubsectionsComponent}
```

And then it becomes pretty simple:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  this.route.paramMap.subscribe( params => {
    this.id_1 = params.get('id1');
    this.id_2 = params.get('id2');

  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have duplicate name for parameters in the route it will overwrite the values.

Use some other name like this.

`{path:'section/:id/:id1', component: SubsectionsComponent}`