# Using query params in Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I am shifting an Ionic 3 project to Ionic 4. This is a web project.

On scanning QR code, page opens. URL looks like:

```
domain.com/qanda/pwa/home?user=simon&skill=ionic&role=Admin&Table=132
```

Till Ionic 3, everything was fine. If I add these params in Ionic 4  and run, it opens `domain.com/qanda/pwa/`  - A blank page, doesn't even open home page by default.

I have kept `.htaccess` file beside `index.html` so that I can directly open any project page from url. Below is the code of `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/qanda/pwa/index.html
```

How can I achieve query params in Ionic 4?

Comment: what library you use to pass param ?  router-link or navigate ?

Answer (score 7):

if you have already URL like you post

```
domain.com/qanda/pwa/home?user=simon&skill=ionic&role=Admin&Table=132
```

Just use ActivatedRoute to get value of param:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute)

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
  if (params) {
    let queryParams = JSON.parse(params);
    console.log(queryParams)
  }
});
}
```

Comment: problem is when i try to open url like this - `https://sapphireprofits.com/qanda/pwa2/home/1/2` where `/1/2` are the parameters, i try to get the url using `this.url = window.location.href;` , it prints `https://sapphireprofits.com/qanda/pwa2/home/` where as it should print `https://sapphireprofits.com/qanda/pwa2/home/1/2` , i have pasted my `.htaccess` above, please guide how can i achieve this ??

Comment: as i understand you call an external domain , it's your domain or someone else ?

Comment: i have hosted app on this domain, its my domain

Comment: can you post the code html and ts file ?? you open this link in ionic app right ?

Comment: ionic project is hosted on this link `https://sapphireprofits.com/qanda/pwa2/index.html`  , if i run `https://sapphireprofits.com/qanda/pwa2/index.html/1/2/3`  it says page doesnt exists` , i have deleted the .htaccess , can you guide how can i grap the variables after `index.html` , this is all i need

Comment: first , do you create the path qanda/pwa2/:id/:user like this in app-routing?

Answer (score 6):

So what you have to do here is follow the route guide (https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5) on angular and make a path with:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'home/:id/:id2/:id3', component: YourComponent},
]
```

Now you add the activeRoute of the previous answer:

```
this.route.params.subscribe((params: any) => {
  if (params['id']) { //id }
  if (params['id2']) { //id2 }
  if (params['id3']) { //id3 }
});
```

Sources:

- [Passing Multiple route params in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36320821/passing-multiple-route-params-in-angular2)
- [How to get multiple ids from route param in Angular 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58077240/how-to-get-multiple-ids-from-route-param-in-angular-6)

Comment: This is correct for path segments (which can be useful), but not for query parameters. You would need to subscribe to `this.route.queryParams` instead to get the query parameters.